# Bash indirect references: ${!t} notation and eval

Tags: bash, eval

I just came along the short notation of bash's indirect references `${!t}`. I'm used to precede indirect references of the kind `\$$t` by `eval`. However, using the `${!t}` notation it seems that I do not need to do this:

```
# d=e e=f; eval y=${!d}; echo $y
f
# d=e e=f; y=${!d}; echo $y
f
```

Why do we need no eval here? Is it implicitly called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From section [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) of the Bash Reference Manual:

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), it introduces a level of variable indirection. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself. This is known as indirect expansion. The exceptions to this are the expansions of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below. The exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to introduce indirection.

The `eval \$$t` version of indirection is manually causing two evaluations of the line contents. The first to get the indirect variable name and the second to get its value.